# False error by eslint-plugin-import for webpack aliases

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, eslint

I am using webpack's aliases in my project. Everything works fine in my original project, but when I clone the project, I get error from `import/no-unresolved` for my webpack aliases:

> Casing of $js/Controller does not match the underlying filesystem  import/no-unresolved

what makes it more interesting is that my project works fine. `import/no-unresolved` seems to send show false error.

For more details, I am adding few links: [.eslintrc.js](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/blob/master/.eslintrc.js), [webpack.config.babel.js](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js), [Link to my Repo](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/)

please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on some editor with a linter? Say Atom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. I installed `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` in order to make Webpack aliases work with eslint resolver. Here is the command to install the plugin:

```
npm install eslint-import-resolver-webpack --save-dev
```

Here is the [link to the repo](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/tree/master/resolvers/webpack)

Comment: Note to others: you need to add the line `"settings": {"import/resolver": "webpack"}` to your `.eslint` config file after installing the aforementioned package.